# MongoDB's Auditing service vs Self created collection to store logs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-fullstack, auditing

I have a fullstack project which's using NodeTS as the backend, and MongoDB as the...DB.

I wish to create a logging mechanism, to monitor changes and different kind of events. That led me to read about auditing option in MongoDB.

I must say, I don't really understand the big difference between using MonogoDB's Auditing service, to just open another collection, let's say 'usersAudits' collection, where in each API request I make, I will have a middleware which is responsible for inserting over there the specific data I need in order to allow me and monitor changes.

Can anyone help me out here? What am I missing?